# Get second column of python csv file as array of ints

Tags: python, arrays, csv, int

I have a csv file that is as follows:

```
                #just want this row as array of ints
8/8/2016 0:00   15804300.00     
8/9/2016 0:00   15805850.00     
8/10/2016 0:00  15807737.50
...
```

I want to get just the second column of numbers (15804300.00...) as an array of integers so it's like:

```
[15804300.00, 15805850.00, 15807737.50...]
```

I'm getting type casting errors but this is what I have so far:

```
filename = 'data.csv' 
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    dataList = list(reader)

    num = []
    for row in dataList:
        num.append(row[0].strip().split('\t'))   #split by tab
```

Any suggestions? Is there an easier way to do this?
Thank you!

Comment: You seem to be getting a list of *floating point numbers*, not integers. Integers have no decimal point, no fractional portion.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is *tab delimited*, tell the `csv.reader()` object to use that delimiter. There should not be any reason to split manually:

```
filename = 'data.csv' 
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    num = [float(row[1]) for row in reader]
```

The list comprehension then picks out the second column of each row, converting the string to a float value.

Demo:

```
>>> import csv
>>> demodata = BytesIO("""\
... 8/8/2016 0:00\t15804300.00
... 8/9/2016 0:00\t15805850.00
... 8/10/2016 0:00\t15807737.50
... """)
>>> with demodata as f:
...     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
...     num = [float(row[1]) for row in reader]
...
>>> num
[15804300.0, 15805850.0, 15807737.5]
```

Comment: thank you! Although im still getting,  an error for this line: num = [float(row[1]) for row in reader] 
ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @helloworld: so some of your values in the second column are not floating point values?

Comment: @helloworld: are you 100% certain of the row format? Perhaps use `for row in reader: print(row[1])` to check? You could use `for row in reader:`, `try:`, `num.append(float(row[1]))`, `except ValueError: pass` to skip any values in the second column that are not convertable.

Comment: i just tried isinstance() and i believe the second columns are strings!

Comment: @helloworld: yes, they are strings. That's not what I asked. `float()` can convert strings that contain the right kind of characters (digits and one decimal point) into a floating point number.

Comment: i just changed the num = [float(row[1]) for row in reader] to str instead of float and it works, thank you i appreciate it!

Comment: @helloworld: you don't need to use `str()` at all if you just want strings: `[row[1] for row in reader]`.

Comment: ohh okay, i see what you are saying, my bad

Comment: was the expected output single decimal or 2 decimal !

Comment: okay did some testing - yes im sure of the row format - it's simply strings. however it still won't let me convert to floats for some reason

Comment: @helloworld: so you have to figure out the exceptions. Use `try: ... except ValueError:` to see what can be converted and what can't.

Comment: @MartijnPieters tried that as well and printed out num afterwards, and got an empty list. It seems like none of the strings can be converted for some reason. still trying to debug

Comment: update: the csv file i was given had extra spaces at the bottom. I deleted those and it worked! Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score -1):

This works

```
import csv
filename = 'data.csv'
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    dataList = list(reader)
    num = []
    for row in dataList:
        num.append(float(row[0].strip().split(' ')[-1]))   #split with spaces, and extract the last item, as it is always the last one

    print num #[15804300.0, 15805850.0, 15807737.5]
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the time of the date-time column? You are building a list of `0:00` strings. That is **not** the exected output.

Comment: why does it matter if the format is standard ? Im just splitting the entities and taking the last item. Unless the format of the data is changed, I see effect of splitting it. @helloworld is this the final format or are you expecting any changes in your data format

Comment: uff my mad, i missed something, let me quickly correct it ;). im returning string of list, must be numerics ..

Comment: Perhaps you didn't realise, but the OP misconfigured the `reader` object; by using the default delimiter no splitting takes place on tabs so they had to split manually. You *do* use `delimiter='\t'` so you no longer have to manually split too...